# Creating video streaming exception in browser's proxy

Tags: firefox, proxy

I'm trying to make Firefox bypass the proxy when loading internet videos. Both adding the domains to No Proxy For field and using the following PAC file doesn't help — it still doesn't download videos directly. What do you think I'm doing wrong here?

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  if (isPlainHostName(host) ||
     dnsDomainIs(host, ".youtube.com") ||
     dnsDomainIs(host, "youtube.com") ||
     dnsDomainIs(host, ".twitch.tv") ||
     dnsDomainIs(host, "twitch.tv")) {
       return "DIRECT";
  } else {
    return "SOCKS5 localhost:4711";
  }
}
```